# pip will not install or download

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

pip does not install anything but instead gives me an error repeatedly then tells me to upgrade pip and when I try to upgrade pip it shows the same error

I have tried different versions of python and they all show the same error

```
C:\Users\zombiekillez>py -m pip install -U pygame
Collecting pygame
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certif
icate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/pygame/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certif
icate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/pygame/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certif
icate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/pygame/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certif
icate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/pygame/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certif
icate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/pygame/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/: There was a problem confi
rming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max r
etries exceeded with url: /simple/pygame/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificatio
nError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to
 get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions:
 )
No matching distribution found for pygame
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

All I want is to install pygame but it won't let me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install python modules without pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103508/how-to-install-python-modules-without-pip)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+certificate+verify+failed%3A+unable+to++get+local+issuer+certificate

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```